# Swift import module

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am new to developing iOS apps, so I'm still on the learning curve and I am experiencing quite a strange problem.

I have a project in which I am using the "Alamofire" module with CocoaPods. Everything is fine and working so far. Then I created another controller in which I want to import the same module, but the resulting message is always "No such module..."

How and why is it working in one file, but does not work in the other? Both files are in the same directory.

P.S. I've tried cleaning the project and also deleting the "DerivedData" folder of Xcode.

Comment: Are you typing `import Alomafire`? The correct spelling is "Alamofire".

Comment: As I said before, it works in one file, but does not in the other. Yes, I use "import Alomafire"

Comment: Is the file target your application target?

Comment: @SaidSikira Do you mean the "Target Membership" in the right panel? If so, then yes. Otherwise I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @NateCook Sorry, I realized just now I am writing in here "Alomafire", but in the code it's "Alamofire", so that isn't the issue.

Anyway I gave up on the CocoaPods and just adding the module manually (as described in the readme of Alamofire) seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your both files Target Membership. It needs to be set to the target you are using:
[image: Targer membership]

Likely, it seems you dragged file into your project and did not set target properly. Check it twice, because there is no other reason for that. Unless your second file is in Test target. In that case add to your pod file:

```
target 'YourTestTarget' do
pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

and run `pod install`